# Функция insertItem работает только один раз (pyqt5, QListwidget)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

У меня есть функция, которая должна взять некоторый айтем из первого QlistWidget (которого нет во втором) и добавить его во второй лист. Для вставки я использую функцию insetItem, но она почему-то срабатывает только один раз (т.е., если первым я добавлю айтем в первый лист, то он добавится только в первый, если во второй, то только во второй) Прикрепляю весь код функции. Scht - счётчик позиции последнего одинакового элемента двух листов.

```
def To_List2_Copy(self):
            global scht
            z = self.List_File1.currentRow()
            item = self.List_File1.takeItem(z)
            item.setBackground(QColor('white'))
            if z != scht:
                    item_push_end = self.List_File1.takeItem(scht)
                    self.List_File1.addItem(item_push_end)
                    self.List_File1.insertItem(scht, item)
            else:
                    self.List_File1.insertItem(scht, item)
            item_push_end_2 = self.List_File2.takeItem(scht)
            item_c = item
            self.List_File2.insertItem(scht, item_c)
            self.List_File2.addItem(item_push_end_2)
            scht = scht + 1
```

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста пример демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Навскидку, итем один, а мест добавления два. Неявное копирование здесь не предусмотрено. Вы же не можете положить одно яблоко сначала в одну корзину, а потом во вторую, не вытаскивая из первой. Нужно создать новое "яблоко".

Comment: @V-Mor только уточните сначала яблоко там или ссылка на яблоко

Comment: Да, @eri абсолютно прав. Я недоглядел, когда писал первый комментарий, что явное копирование всё же выполняется. Но если это ссылка на одно и то же "яблоко", то потребуется заменить копирование ссылки явным созданием нового объекта.

Answer (score 1):

```
def To_List2_Copy(self):
            global scht
            z = self.List_File1.currentRow()
            item = self.List_File1.takeItem(z)
            item.setBackground(QColor('white'))
            buffer = self.List_File1.item(scht).text()
            item_c = self.List_File1.item(scht)
            item_c.setBackground(QColor('white'))
            item_c.setText(item.text())
            x = self.List_File1.count()
            push_to_end = self.List_File2.takeItem(scht)
            self.List_File2.insertItem(scht, item)
            self.List_File2.addItem(push_to_end)
            self.List_File1.addItem(buffer)
            item = self.List_File1.item(x)
            item.setBackground(QColor('red'))
            scht = scht + 1
```

Всё заработало, разобрался сам, вот код

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте проработать это все через [Model/View](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#)

Item будут создаваться и удаляться сами при изменении модели.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonicam это stackoverflow на русском, Поэтому комментарии нужно оставлять на русском языке

Comment: @Grundy - у него раскладка сломалась на маке)

Comment: @eri, это конечно хорошо, но при этом иногда он пишет на русском иногда нет ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ и не похоже что это связано с физической невозможностью писать.

Comment: это было год назад, наверное уже починил)